# How prevalent is editing to promote in 'active' list?

Tags: discussion, edits, bump

How prevalent is editing questions/answers where you've participated to bring them back up the 'active' list? Since edits from more reputable users don't seem to need reviews this is probably easier to do for them.

A related question is whether an edit to a question/answer that needs peer review promotes the question up the 'active' list before the review? I could give it a try but it is easier to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I suspect this happens from time to time, but it is hard to detect. As long as the edit is actually improving the post (e.g. by correcting a grammatical error) and it doesn't happen too often, it is not a real problem. The turnover rate of questions on Stack Overflow is so high that the potential benefits are minimal. If you see a user do this *repeatedly*, you could flag one of his posts for moderator attention, as [bumping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bump/info) is not one of the purposes of edits.

> A related question is whether an edit to a question/answer that needs peer review promotes the question up the 'active' list before the review?

No, it doesn't. The question will get 'bumped' only the moment the edit is approved.